# Find the pattern of this grid?

Tags: number-theory

I just have a quiz problem that I have absolutely no idea what's the answer is.

The problem is:

What number should the question mark be?

```
2 | 4 | 0
---------
1 | 2 | 4
---------
3 | 1 | 3
---------
36| ? | 91
```

Comment: is the answer $6\times8=48$?

Comment: @MonK I correct the last 96 to 91, sorry for this typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raise all numbers to the power of 3 and add the columns:

$$2^3 + 1^3 + 3^3 = 8 + 1 + 27 = 36$$

$$0^3 + 4^3 + 3^3 = 0 + 64 + 27 = 91$$

so

$$ 4^3 + 2^3 + 1^3 = 64 + 8 + 1 = 73$$